# Text output from "Just" library in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing a program in Swift that uses [Just](https://github.com/JustHTTP/Just) to fetch a webpage. I am new to Swift and know very little about it. My code is simple:

```
let r = Just.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(r.statusCode!)
print(r.text)
```

I would expect to see the contents of the downloaded web page, however, the output is:

```
200
nil
```

How can I retrieve the text contents of the response?

Comment: Try to `print(r)` and see what you get in the console. That should give a hint as to what keys you'll need to use to get the data.

Comment: `print(r)` returns `GET https://www.google.com/ 200`

Comment: My bad. That `statusCode` tricked me into thinking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your URL. If you'll try this, your response won't be nil:

```
let r = Just.get("https://medium.com/")
    print(r.text!)
}
```

Comment: @DylanKlomparens I've updated my answer. Please, check it

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Any idea why medium.com works while www.google.com does not?

Comment: @DylanKlomparens I think, Google just blocks it content